In John's gospel, Jesus says he cannot do anything of himself but only what God tells him to do. If so, how then can Jesus be God?
John 5:19 ESV

So Jesus replied, "Truly, truly, I tell you, the Son can do nothing
by Himself, unless He sees the Father doing it. For whatever the
Father does, the Son also does.

John 7:16 ESV

"My teaching is not My own," Jesus replied. "It comes from Him
who sent Me."

John 8:26-29 ESV

I have much to say about you and much to judge, but He who sent me
is true, and I declare to the world what I have heard from Him.”
They did not understand that he had been speaking to them about the
Father. So Jesus said to them, “When you have lifted up the Son of
Man, then you will know that I am he, and that I do nothing on my
own authority, but speak just as the Father taught me. And He who
sent me is with me. He has not left me alone, for I always do the
things that are pleasing to Him.”

John 12:49-50 ESV

For I have not spoken on my own authority, but the Father who sent
me has himself given me a commandment—what to say and what to speak.
And I know that his commandment is eternal life. What I say,
therefore, I say as the Father has told me.”

John 14:24 ESV

Whoever does not love Me does not keep My words. The word that you
hear is not My own, but it is from the Father who sent Me.

The lesson from these passages are:

Jesus can do nothing by himself but does only what the Father is
doing.

Jesus teachings are not his own as they come from the Father.

Jesus declared to the world what he heard from the Father.

Jesus does nothing of his own authority, but speaks only what the Father has taught him to say.

Jesus' words are not his own, but the Father's.


The Father is clearly God, but how can Jesus be God if he is clearly God's Son?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If Jesus cannot do anything himself but only what God tells him to do, then how can Jesus be God?
While this is not directly about the trinity, take the trinity for example:
God is three in terms of personhood and one in terms of essence.
In this case the answer is simple: one member of the Trinity doesn't act independently of the others.

How can Jesus be God?
The context just prior to this states:

John 5:18 - Therefore the Jews sought all the more to kill Him,
because He not only broke the Sabbath, but also said that God was His Father, making Himself equal with God.

Let's look at the claim:

Jesus claims that He can do nothing of Himself but only what He sees
the Father doing.
Humans, created in God’s image, have moral independence and are
distinct from God, leading to the possibility of moral separation (as
with Adam’s sin).
Jesus, while distinct from the Father, claims no moral independence
from God, indicating a unique unity.
No human can claim the same type of unity with God as Jesus does, as
humans naturally have moral independence from God.

Conclusion: Therefore, Jesus’ claim to do nothing of Himself but only what He sees the Father doing, coupled with the unique unity He describes, would imply that He is equal with God as stated prior.

I like and dislike analogies. All analogies break down, but one analogy that might help is: A triangle is one shape with three corners. Each corner is distinct, yet they all share the same essence of being part of the triangle.

Unity but distinctness: A triangle is one single shape with
three distinct corners. => The Trinity is one God in three
distinct persons (Father, Son, and Holy Spirit). Each person of the
Trinity is distinct while sharing the same divine essence.
Co-existence: Three corners of a triangle coexist simultaneously;
none is more or less part of the triangle than the others. => The Father,
Son, and Holy Spirit coexist eternally and are all fully God.
Interrelatedness: The corners of a triangle are interrelated; the
existence of one implies the existence of the others, and they all
contribute to the identity of what we call a triangle. => In the Trinity,
the persons are interrelated, and their relationships define their
collective identity as one God.
Indivisibility: A triangle cannot be divided into its corners without
ceasing to be a triangle. => The Trinity cannot be divided
into the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit without losing the essence of
the one God.



Throughout Jesus’ ministry he was communicating his divine origins.

John 3:13 – The Son of Man is in heaven and came down from it.
John 5:37 – No man (including Israel) had seen or heard the voice of    the Father, except the Son.
John 7:16 – The doctrines Christ taught were not learned in    synagogue, but came from the Father.
John 8:42 – Jesus proceeded forth and “came from God”.
John 10:30 – Jesus declares unity with the Father in the Godhead. The    Jews took up stones to stone him for making “thyself God” (John
10:33).

Everything Jesus did was something God did. This is the point Jesus
makes when he says he does nothing of himself, because his will and
actions are inseparable from that of the Father in perfect union in
the Godhead.
Jesus does nothing of himself because there are three persons in the
Godhead, and Jesus and the Father are one in the Godhead. None of them
can do anything of themselves. Take away the Father, and Jesus can do
nothing. Take away the Son, and the Father can do nothing for our
salvation. Take away the Father, Son, or Spirit as God and you have a
different God. [1]


Note: These questions have been covered extensively because nearly every religious group attacks the doctrine of the trinity. Including: Jehovah’s Witnesses, Mormonism (Latter-day Saints), Islam, Iglesia ni Cristo, Christian Science, Mother God Cult (World Mission Society Church of God), Oneness Pentecostals, Unitarian Groups, and some Hebrew Roots.

People keep asking how the trinity can be true if the word Trinity is not found in the Bible. But Christians who believe in the Trinity only use this word as a label for a much deeper and broader summary of "what we think the Bible overall tells us about God's nature." Just as my Christology is "the things I believe about Jesus", and my ecclesiology is "the things I believe about the church."

which God (son, father or HS) spoke to Moses, Adam, Cain, abraham, his wife, Job etc...?
